# Radio button onClick action

Tags: android, onclick, radio-button

I need to open last Linear Layout after clicking a radio button
given is my xml code
i need to show the last linear layout which has 2 buttons after clicking male radio button till then it shoud be hidden.
I tried alot but i failed im fresher and im still learning andrroid
                                                ...............
...................
..................
................
if any suggestions please amil @ byhaqi.fuzail@yahoo.com

```
<LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:orientation="vertical">





    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="Button"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="76dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="167dp" />
    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/rg">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="male"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"

            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:id="@+id/rone"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/rtwo"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="female"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
    </RadioGroup>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:visibility="gone"
        >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="Button"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="76dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="167dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this is my java file
package com.example.syed.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    }
}

Comment: If your comment is supposed to add to your question, them please include it, and format it as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
RadioGroup radioGrp = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.yourRadioGroup);        
radioGrp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedRadioId) {
        // checkedRadioId is the RadioButton selected
        // You can set Visibility Logic here if checkId is of Male Radio button
    }
});
```